# Braintree form submit button is disabled even after fixing Drop in UI errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, braintree

I'm using Braintree Drop in UI, and it seems it has some bug. When there is an error in the payment fields(e.g. credit card number is blank), the containing form submit button gets disabled, which is OK, however if I fixed these error(e.g. by entering a valid value for credit card), the submit button is still disabled. So am I doing something wrong here ?

My code is simple(using Ruby on Rails ? & HAML)

```
%script{"src" => "https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.27.0.min.js"}

:javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
      braintree.setup(MY_TOKEN, "dropin", {
        container: $("#payment-form"),
        defaultFirst: true
      });
    })
```

Comment: open the console and check for any errors

Comment: The Drop-in UI doesn't automatically enable or disable a form's submit button - could you post the code for your payment form?

Answer (score 2):

Well I figured it :) Rails add `data-disable-with` attribute to form submit buttons created with `submit_tag`, which disable clicking on the submit button twice, so just use

```
 submit_tag "Pay", data: { disable_with: false }
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with this:

add `onError: enableSubmitButton` to init options for `braintree.setup`, and here is my function(coffeescript):

```
enableSubmitButton = (obj) ->
  setTimeout(() ->
    $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false)
  , 500)
```

I'm not sure why, but it doesn't work without timeout. I understand that it's not a super-stable solution, but it works in most cases.

Still looking for a solution without timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check my answer to the question I posted now :)

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba I don't want to disable this feature at all - it's kinda useful to prevent race-condition bugs. I just want it to work nice with braintree validation errors :)